# LINQ-to-Entities null conditional on navigation property on anonymous class

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am selecting an anonymous class in a LINQ-to-Entities query:

```
  var users = (from u in db.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.ID).Skip(skip).Take(200)
  select new{
              u.ID, u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.Gender, u.IsEnabled, u.Media
            }).ToList();
```

The problem is with the media column. `Media` is a navigation property, that may have zero or more objects. `Media` is a class where it has a `URL` property, which has its own table and navigation property on `User`. I want to select an anonymous class such as:

```
select new{
              u.ID, u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.Gender, u.IsEnabled, "u.Media's first items URL proprty, or null/empty string if u.Media is empty"
            }).ToList();
```

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: It hurts my eyes when fluent and query syntax is mixed! On topic: Can't you just inline that like: `u.Media.Any() ? u.Media.First().Url : null`?

Comment: I also hate that kind of syntax, but it was the best way to explain it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a `linq-to-enities` query you can do this, no need to worry about null reference exceptions.

```
u.Media.FirstOrDefault().Url
```

Comment: That worked, but with a minor change. It first threw an exception telling that I should use `FirstOfDefault` instead of `First`, and I've did it then it worked. So my final code is `u.Media.FirstOrDefault().URL`

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu - interesting, [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550(v=vs.100).aspx) states [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348657(v=vs.100).aspx) is a supported method...am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure.. but it was Entity Framework's (or LINQ's) own exception telling me to change to FirstOrDefault.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu - Which version of Entity Framework are you using?